# 'ON December 7-8' or 'IN December 7-8'?

Tags: prepositions

On the one hand, it's a period, not a single day. On the other hand, it's just two days (doesn't matter how short it is, does it?). What preposition should I choose?

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should say "**On December 7-8**.'

You would use '**in**' when you are specifying a month or a year but not a day, such as, "**in May**," or "**in 1998**."